# VR 360 video playback in Unity app is constantly choppy, not at all smooth on Oculus Quest 2

Tags: unity-game-engine, video, oculus, oculusquest

I'm building a simple 360 monoscopic video player app in Unity for Oculus Quest 2. The video is 4096x2048 30fps mp4 which plays very smoothly in the Oculus TV app but inside my app, it's constantly choppy as if it were 15fps or lower. I have tried many encoding options, tried using the AVPro demo plugin but no luck.

I followed this tutorial: https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/play-360-video-with-a-skybox-in-unity

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: I don't use Unity but it sounds like the Occulus TV app is GPU accelerated but maybe the player in your code is not accelerated. Check the Unity manual/forums about GPU video playback. Another option is to use a smaller resolution of video (test for best size with smooth playback).

Comment: I can't give you much other than assurance that you're on the right track. I'm playing 4k video with the same resolution on a skybox right now and I can get 30-60fps. To help you narrow the possible problems down, try playing video from this site https://www.mettle.com/360vr-master-series-free-360-downloads-page/. If it's still choppy, it's something in your project. If it's smooth, your videos are the problem. Try "Ayutthaya – Easy Tripod Paint:" it played smoothly with my player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the mismatch between the 30 fps video and the default 72 Hz display refresh rate of the Quest 2. I set the frequency to 90 with this line of code

```
Unity.XR.Oculus.Performance.TrySetDisplayRefreshRate(90f);
```

...and now the video plays smoothly.